# How Reset vector of CPU is fixed

Tags: bootloader

As everyone knows, CPU starts execution from reset vector address. But How that address is fixed for any CPU. How CPU comes to know that fetch instruction from reset vector address.
where will be the reset vector address will be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed in the same way that all the other functions like `add number A to number B` are fixed, it is a collection of transistors that make up gates that provide functions.

In the same way there are a collection of transistors and circuits that make up the program counter and they will be set up such that when a reset signal is received then the default value is set to the reset vector value.

You could think of it as a collection of gates connected on the side of the program counter that has only one input which is the reset signal. When that signal is received then the processor is stopped and those gates are triggered. They will push the various bits within the program counter register up and down to match the reset vector.

In that way, the reset vector is a fundamental feature of the way the circuit inside the processor is constructed.